# What does image gradient mean in the following paper?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, gradient

I am working in digital image processing using java, recently I am implementing a paper in java, One portion of this paper is this:
[image]

What I have understood from that is, G(i,j) would be intensity of image at location (i, j) after applying **soble operator** on it, does it mean so or anything else,

I have used the following code to compute wG,

```
public void weightedGCalc() {
    BufferedImage sobelIm = this.getSobelImage();
    int width = sobelIm.getWidth();
    int height = sobelIm.getHeight();
    weightedG = new double[width][height];

    for (int row = 0; row < width; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < height; col++) {
            int imgPix = new Color(sobelIm.getRGB(row, col)).getRed();
            float val = -(float) (Math.pow(imgPix, 2) / (2 * Math.pow(SIGMA_G[5], 2)));
            weightedG[row][col] = (float) Math.exp(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Here **this.getSobelImage();** will give me **sobel Image** of a given image. I am working with **gray level** images hence i am considering only one plane (RED). Here **SIGMA_G[5]** contains value of sigmaG as suggested by **Author**.

Comment: This question basically requires help in programming portion, so this in not off the topic, down voters or people who will wish to close this question, kindly mention your comments...

Comment: +1 for your announcement. :)

Comment: **down voters or people who will wish to close this question, kindly mention your comments**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. By gradient, I think the author actually means the gradient magnitude of the image. Convolution with sobel operators is one way of calculating the gradient of an image.

[image]

and

[image]

(Gx,Gy), an image of vectors is the gradient of the image.

[image]

This G is the gradient magnitude of the image and is what you get from `this.getSobelImage()`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here gradient means the results obtained by the Sobel operator. Means the final outcome of the Sobel operators processing on the given image.

So after applying the Sobel function on a floating point image. The resultant image will be the gradient image.

Comment: Ok, nice explanation.